# How to expunge a page from BlueSpice MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

On a MediaWiki that is using BlueSpice, if a page gets created I can delete it, but what if I want to completely expunge its record, how can I remove all traces of a page I do not want so that it can no longer be recovered or viewed/seen in any way, as if it had never been created in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nukePage.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:NukePage.php) can permanently remove a page. You might want to run [`refreshLinks.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RefreshLinks.php) afterwards.

[`deleteArchivedRevisions.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteArchivedRevisions.php) permanently removes *all* deleted pages/revisions.